# What does this command do in Linux iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

What does this command do and how to revert this command.   in linux.

> `iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Will It cause any problem?

Answer (score 1):

That line says accept inbound connections coming in to eth1 interface that are tcp destined to port 80. In other words, accept traffic coming in to the server to whatever address in on eth1 if it's destined for the web server, or whatever other service is running on port 80 (which is generally a web server).